# Free and Open Source Screen and Audio Recorder for Debian

Tags: open-source, screen-recording, audio-recording, debian

I need a FOSS software which has following capabilities:

- Records audio
- Records external monitor screen
- Has a feature to pause a video
- Has shortcut keys to start, stop and pause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an app, named [vokoscreen](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/video/vokoscreen).

Answer (score 0):

[OBS](https://obsproject.com/) is a popular choice, and can do pretty much anything you would want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in details the features provided, but Gnome [comes with a native screencast application](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/screen-shot-record.html.en#screencast) and Debian ships also [Kazam](https://packages.debian.org/buster/kazam)

Personally, I use [Peek](https://packages.debian.org/buster/peek) with [Screenkey](https://packages.debian.org/buster/screenkey)